# Filter on an Integer field in Realm

Tags: java, realm

If the `id` attribute in an object is of type `Integer`, how do I filter the query to return all objects whose `id` contains part of a query. i.e. what is the equivalent Realm `contains` filter operator for Integers?

e.g. `object1` has `id:1234`. If I query `123` then it should return `object1`. The only filter available for Integers that comes close is `equalTo` but for this to work I would have to pass `1234` to the query.

Comment: Why would a query for 123 return an object with an id of 1234? what about an object with 12345, or 123456? It sounds like you may be looking for an object with a known primary key. If so, see my answer. If not, clarify the question and I will update my answer. Also, and integer doesn't *contain* anything other than the integer. If you want to look for sub-strings, that's a totally different type of object, typically a string.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to add helper field that represent your `id` as `String` and query `contains()` based on this field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `Integer` field to `String` and then you can filter from `Realm` in this way

```
realm.where(YourRealmModel.class).contains("id","123").findAll()
```

Comment: So there is no way to keep the `id` field as an `Integer` and filter for part of the `id`?

Comment: as far as I know, no such way.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to access an object via it's a primary key of id. You can access that object directly with the following code without a query. Assuming we have a DogClass:

```
class DogClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id = NSUUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var dog_name = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

let realm = try! Realm()
let primaryKey = 123
guard let thisDog = realm.object(ofType: DogClass.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey) else { return }
print(thisDog.dog_name)
```